# Ta-Lib python: installation failed

Tags: python, ta-lib

I'm trying to install TA-Lib module on my 3.6 Python, but i'm facing many problems. First of all, i already made sure that it's the x32 version. I have two versions of python installed, 2.7 and 3.6.

Here is what i tried:

```
pip install ta-lib
```

I got the error error: command `'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory.`

After that, i tried downloading it from here, but after running `pip install TA_Lib-0.4.15-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl`, i got the following error: `requirement 'TA_Lib-0.4.15-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist.`

Did anyone else experience a similar problem or knows how to solve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: To install for Python 3, you should use `pip3`. Or `python3 -m pip install ta-lib`

Comment: Tried that too, with the same result

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the cp38 wrapper (0.4.19) instead if cp39 doesn't work.

Worked for me.

I am using Anaconda 4.9.2 with Python 3.8.5,  64 bit version.

1. Download - TA_Lib‑0.4.19‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl

Link : [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib)

2. pip install TA_Lib‑0.4.19‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 0):

Clone the GitHub repository and run `setup.py`.

```
$> https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib
$> python setup.py install
```

Comment: So it cloned the repository but when i try setup.py i get 'no such file or directory'. I found the repository and copied it to my site-packages folder of py 3.6 and then tried pip install ta-lib, but i got 'cl.exe failed' again

Comment: Ok. So what is your platform?

Comment: Okay, other than that, before getting cl.exe failed, i got 'Failed building wheel for TA-Lib'

Comment: I got python 3.6 and 2.7 on my laptop (Windows), is python x32 so it should be fine for ta-lib

Comment: First, install this! [cpp build tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools).
Then try again!

Comment: I got VS installed, i tried pretty much everything but nothing seems to work, don't know what i'm missing

Comment: Your main problem is likely to be trying to use 64-bit Python with the 32-bit binary release of the ta-lib C library.

Comment: Well, i tried                                                                                          `import struct
print(struct.calcsize("P") * 8)`, and it gave me 32 as a result, so it should be a 32 bit version. I had the same doubt, tho, but it seems not to be this case

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution on a githib repo and it worked for me.

Download TA_Lib-0.4.10-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib.

And use command
pip install TA_Lib-0.4.10-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

I was using anaconda with Python 3.6 64 bit version.

Link to github repo : https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/issues/127